# handle componentDidCatch for all react components

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am looking at my options to do error handling in my react app. For the same, Error Boundary seems to be a good option.

One option is to wrap outermost components in Error Boundary but this is not desired for me as the fallback UI will replace the whole app component. Other option is to wrap all the components individually.

Instead of manually wrapping all components in Error Boundary, is there a way in which I can handle componentDidCatch of all components implicitly at one place?

Comment: Have you thought about a Higher Order component?

Comment: yeah HOC is the way to go. but I will have to wrap individual components manually with an Error Boundary HOC. I am looking for some implicit way.